# How to display coordinates from db in OSM

Tags: database, laravel, leaflet, coordinates, openstreetmap

In DB i have 5 tables, and in one of them i have devices with coordinates. I want to show that devices on Open Street Map, but don't know how to show it from DB to map.
I even have that table in same blade with map.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: You can use ajax from jquery (Javascript) to get data from a php file. The php file read the data from the db out and give it back to js. From there you can create a Marker with the coordinates. Db read: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp  . Marker creation: https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/#markers-circles-and-polygons and Ajax call: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: I'm already got that all. Data from db are shower in table in Laravel blade, and I have script with already drawned custom markers and path on OSM. Now I gues, I need to put that data in json array and show it on map?

Comment: Can you pls create a example on jsfiddle.com

Comment: I made it, but somehow it cant be shown properly.
https://jsfiddle.net/j8grx0sz/1/

Comment: get you an error? Or what is not working? The code looks ok. The variable `koordinate` is defined twice, you know that?

Comment: I removed this one - var koordinate = [{{$dev -> x}}, {{$dev -> y }}], now I have         var koordinate = {!! json_encode($dev->toArray()) !!}; and now I'm get this error "Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()".

Comment: What output you get with this: `var koordinate = [{{$dev -> x}}, {{$dev -> y }}]; console.log(koordinate);`

Comment: I got this: Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined)

Comment: Ok. remove the line again. What do you get with: `var koordinate = {!! json_encode($device->toArray()) !!}; console.log(koordinate);` I changed the `$dev` to `$device`

Comment: Now I have array with that data in console. Error was from next code "for(var=0...)".
How can I show that array on map, with $each code or something?

Comment: Come to the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203897/discussion-between-goran-bl-and-falke-design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove: `var koordinate = [{{$dev -> x}}, {{$dev -> y }}];`

Change `$dev` to `$device` `var koordinate = {!! json_encode($device->toArray()) !!};`

And use this Code to add the Markers:

```
for (var i=0; i < koordinate.length; i++) {
   if(koordinate[i].x && koordinate[i].y){
     var marker = L.marker([koordinate[i].x, koordinate[i].y])
     .bindPopup(""+koordinate[i].device_type)
     .addTo(map);
   }
}
```